# Do I need to pass in the url to call a WCF web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asmx

I'm updating my clients web service from the obsolete ASP.NET ASMX and the and the Microsoft.NET WSE library to the newer WCF implementation. But I don't have enough doc to know if I need to pass in a url such as the code below?

In the old style, the url was observed from sometwhere in the web service library, and in the new call I had to enter in the url to connect and create the channel factory. I'm just wondering if the url can be bypassed like with the old style?

Here is the old code

```
_TrustCurrentWebServices = new WebServiceAWI();
_User = new User();
_User.UserName = _TrustCurrentWebServices.EncryptValue(_BPWebServicesUserName);
_User.Password = _TrustCurrentWebServices.EncryptValue(_BPWebServicesPassword);
```

Hre is the new code. I don't want to have to pass in the url!

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport); 
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(_Url);
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WebServiceAWI>(binding, endpoint);
_WebServiceAWI = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

_User = new User();
_User.UserName = _WebServiceAWI.EncryptValue(_BPWebServicesUserName);
_User.Password = _WebServiceAWI.EncryptValue(_BPWebServicesPassword);
```

I tried

```
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WebServiceAWI>(binding);
```

but received an exception that said I need an endpoint address!

Answer (score 0):

When calling the service by creating the channel with ChannelFactory, you could refer to following code snippets to set up the client credentials.

```
Server end(10.157.13.69, Console app)
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://localhost:11011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;

            using (ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), uri))
            {
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "");
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb;
                smb = sh.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
                if (smb == null)
                {
                    smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
                    {
                        HttpsGetEnabled = true
                    };
                    sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                }
                sh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
                sh.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustUserNamePasswordVal();
                Binding mexbinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding();
                sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), mexbinding, "mex");

                sh.Opened += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is ready");
                };
                sh.Closed += delegate
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Service is clsoed");
                };


                sh.Open();

                Console.ReadLine();
                sh.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

        }
    }
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello();
    }
    public class MyService : IService
    {
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return $"Hello Stranger,{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        }
    }
    internal class CustUserNamePasswordVal : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName != "jack" || password != "123456")
            {
                throw new Exception("Username/Password is not correct");
            }
        }
}
```

**Client invocation.**

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
            {
                return true;
            };
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://10.157.13.69:11011"));
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "jack";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "123456";
            IService sv = factory.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                var result = sv.SayHello();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channelfactory-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.